# Unable to retrieve metadate

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity

I am learning `ASP.NET` according this tutorial (MvcMusicStore project):

http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/

And in the PDF file page 55 i need to Add controller:

[image]

And get this error:

[image]

I try to add this controller from several machines and get this error all the time.
What does it mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the MvcMusicStore app is not updated. The reason is because you are not using the **Compact Edition** of the database.

Update your connection string that is found in the tutorial to

```
<add name="MusicStoreEntities" connectionString="Data Source=DBInstanceName;Initial Catalog=MvcMusicStore;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```